# Material UI Tabpanel not using columns

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  title: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "block",
      maxHeight: 125,
    },
  },
  Alert: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  Logo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginRight: theme.spacing(3),
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
    },
  },
}));

export default function ScrollableTabsButtonForce() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs
          className={classes.title}
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="on"
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          aria-label="scrollable force tabs example"
        >
          <Tab
            label="Elite Knight"
            icon={<img className={classes.Logo} src={Knight} alt="Logo" />}
            {...a11yProps(0)}
          />
          <Tab
            label="Royal Paladin"
            icon={<img className={classes.Logo} src={Paladin} alt="Logo" />}
            {...a11yProps(1)}
          />
          <Tab
            label="Master Sorcerer"
            icon={<img className={classes.Logo} src={Sorcerer} alt="Logo" />}
            {...a11yProps(2)}
          />
          <Tab
            label="Elder Druid"
            icon={<img className={classes.Logo} src={Druid} alt="Logo" />}
            {...a11yProps(3)}
          />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
        <Alert className={classes.Alert} severity="info">
          For more information on how to make a purchase please click on the
          desired script!
        </Alert>
      </Grid>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Cards voc={0} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Cards voc={1} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        <Cards voc={2} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
        <Cards voc={3} />
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the cards component it loops on a table and generate cards for the other component i already declared how many columns for each screen.

no matter what i tried it keeps each card on a row, i tried display: "Flex" still same issue.

tried declaring the columns on seprate divs aswell still same issue.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Added a photo, the cards are not on the same row they're breaking the line.

Comment: you mean you wanted them on one row? can you show us more code?

Comment: added the component, yes i one the looped cards in same row

Comment: here is the cards component https://pastebin.com/ituvjUch

Comment: can you create a reproducable sandbox? I have created the base based on the code you sent, can you fork it and update it? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-ovm4w?file=/MUItest.js